# how to get data from web service using webclient method in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using web client method to consume data from web service. In my textblock the data that i am getting from the web service is the source code of the link that i have given. Here i am attaching my code

```
public about()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>



        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
        xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
        <soap:Body>
        <getarvindAbout xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"" />
        </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>");

        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webclient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://ws.clearwintech.com/arvind.asmx?op=getarvindAbout"));
```

}

In the textblock i want the data from the getarvindAbout method. But i am just getting the source code here. Can anyone please help me to accomplish this task

```
    void webclient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        String str = e.Result;

        textBlock1.Text = str;

    }
```

Comment: why you can't Add Service Reference to your project?

Comment: its not working...i tried a lot.........

Comment: When you try to add what does happen?

Comment: @VitorCanova It is added succesfully but the output that i am getting is my application name.service name. ArrayofXElement

Comment: When you are in "Add Service Reference" window did you choose to map list to Generic List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at these links:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/connecting-windows-phone-7-with-aspnet-web-pages
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/creating-a-webservice-with-webmatrix-and-consuming-it-with-a-windows-7-phone-application
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devfish/archive/2011/04/06/webclient-windows-phone-services-consumption-part-1.aspx